# Conversion of x axis in DFT strictly for the case of unequally spaced samples in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, fft, dft

I'm facing a problem for the conversion of x axis from DFT. As my sample model of my x axis is in meters (m) and y axis represents the rho (scattering length density). After taking the `fft(rho)` in matlab I will get the intensity but I cannot figure out how I should get the x axis. I want to know if there is a specific formula or limits to calculate the x axis after DFT.

Here is my source code, 
I just want the values for my x axis:

```
al=100;
nipam=20;
water=300;
j=1;
for i=1:15
  rho(j:j+al)=2.07;
  k=j+al;
  rho(k:k+nipam)=0.81;
  l=k+nipam;
  rho(l:l+water)=-0.56;
  m=l+water;
  rho(m:m+nipam)=0.81;
  j=m+nipam;
end
del_x=1;
xmax=6600;
x=(0:del_x:xmax);
% plot(x,rho)
A=abs(fft(rho));
I=A.^2;
% del_q=2*pi./xmax;   I want to how should I get the x axis???after doing    FFT 
% qmax=2*pi./del_x;
% q=(0:del_q:qmax);
plot(q,I)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `plot(x, rho)` is the correct plot of your “time-domain” (spatial domain in your case), then the following is the correct axes in the frequency domain:

```
q1 = [0 : length(x) - 1] / length(x)] / diff(x(1:2)); % q1 in units of cycles per meter
plot(q1, abs(fft(rho)))
```

Here, `q1` runs from 0 to just less than the sample rate implicit in `x`. Because of the symmetry of the DFT for real inputs, you can also think about the frequency axis running from `-0.5 * sample rate` to just less than `0.5 * sample rate`:

```
q2 = q1 - diff(x(1:2)) / 2; % still cycles per meter
plot(q2, abs(fftshift(fft(rho))))
```

Note here that I shift both the frequency axis and the frequency-domain coefficients themselves with `fftshift`.

Also note that if you want the frequency axis in other units, you can scale them. E.g., `2 * pi * q2` puts them in units of radians per meter, since you can interpret `2 * pi`’s units as radians per cycle.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes,but strictly for the case of unequally spaced samples.Do my x-axis will change except multiplying with `2 * pi * q` and of course 'q' will run from `q=(1:length(x)-1)`